# En caso de que todos los números sean iguales no los ordene

Tags: java

En el siguiente programa le pido al usuario un arreglo de la cantidad de números que el quiera para posteriormente ordenarlos, pero también tiene que realizar la siguiente instrucción "determinar si son iguales y si no lo son ordenarlos de menor a mayor". Con ayuda del método burbuja se ordenan los números de esta forma pero no entiendo como comprobar si todos son iguales. es lo único que falta ocupo saber como hacer esto para indicar que todos los números son iguales y finalice el programa.

Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Eje{

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner usuario = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;
int aux=0;

System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de elementos de la lista: ");
n = usuario.nextInt();
int lista[] = new int [n];
System.out.println("Ingrese los "+ n +" valores enteros: ");

for(int i=0; i<n ; i++){
System.out.println(("Digite el valor "+(i+1)+":"));
lista[i]=usuario.nextInt();}

for(int j=0; j < n ; j++ ){
for(int i=0; i<n-1 ; i++){
if(lista[i]>lista[i+1]){
aux = lista[i];
lista[i] = lista[i+1];
lista[i+1] = aux;
}
}
}

int k=0;
System.out.println("Numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
while(k<n){
System.out.print(lista[k]+" - ");
k++;

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien quieres saber si son todos iguales mostrar que son todos iguales y en caso contrario mostrarlos ordenados.

Por cierto buenos días.

La solución que veo es declarar una variable boolean en false y añadir un else if (lista[i] == lista[i + 1]) {
iguales = true;
}
Después si la boolean es true es que son iguales y muestro un texto de que lo son y en caso contrario los muestro ordenados:

Te pongo el código completo tal cual lo he dejado yo, espero que te sirva.

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Eje {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner usuario = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        int aux = 0;
        boolean iguales = false;
        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de elementos de la lista: ");
        n = usuario.nextInt();
        int lista[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Ingrese los " + n + " valores enteros: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(("Digite el valor " + (i + 1) + ":"));
            lista[i] = usuario.nextInt();
        }
        usuario.close(); // Cierro el Scanner
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                if (lista[i] > lista[i + 1]) {
                    aux = lista[i];
                    lista[i] = lista[i + 1];
                    lista[i + 1] = aux;
                } else if (lista[i] == lista[i + 1]) {// Compruebo si son todos iguales
                    iguales = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (iguales) {// Si son todos iguales
            System.out.println("Todos los números son iguales");
        } else {// En caso contrario los muestro ordenados
            int k = 0;
            System.out.println("Numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
            while (k < n) {
                System.out.print(lista[k] + " - ");
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Tu ejemplo no es correcto porque si introduces 3 elementos en la lista e indicas que los valores sean: 1,1,2 saldrá el mensaje "Todos los números son iguales" porque solo estas comparando el primer valor del array con el segundo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Robert Gutiérrez me fue de mucha ayuda :)

Comment: Hola Buhoo, me alegro de que te haya servido de ayuda, para eso estamos todos aquí, marcala como aceptada si puedes, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo una solución muy parecida a la tuya.

En vez de ordenar el array con el método de ordenamiento burbuja, simplemente puedes hacer esto:

```
Arrays.sort(lista);
```

Ahora comprobamos si todos los valores de la lista están repetidos, mostraremos un mensaje en ese caso.

En caso contrario mostraremos la lista ordenada de menor a mayor.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < lista.length; j++) {
        if (lista[i] == lista[j]) {
            iguales = true;
        }else {
            iguales = false;
        }
    }
}

if (iguales) {
    System.out.println("Todos los números son iguales");
} else {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lista));
}
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean iguales = false;

        System.out.print("Digite la cantidad de elementos de la lista: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int lista[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Ingrese los " + n + " valores enteros: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(("Digite el valor " + (i + 1) + ": "));
            lista[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        sc.close();

        Arrays.sort(lista);

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lista.length; j++) {
                if (lista[i] == lista[j]) {
                    iguales = true;
                }else {
                    iguales = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (iguales) {
            System.out.println("Todos los números son iguales");
        } else {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lista));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias DevMind me gusto lo del Arrays.sort(lista); no lo conocía pero veo que fue de mucha ayuda. También me agrado que si solo un numero es diferente aun así los ordene. :)

Comment: Me alegro wu que te haya servido mi respuesta. Por favor marcarla como aceptada y vota positivamente :)